# MSVC regular expression match

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

I am trying to match a literal number, e.g. 1600442 using a set of regular expressions in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. My regular expressions are simply:

```
1600442|7654321
7895432
```

The problem is that both of the above matches the string.

Implementing this in Python gives the expected result:
import re

```
serial = "1600442"
re1 = "1600442|7654321"
re2 = "7895432"

m = re.match(re1, serial)
if m:
    print "found for re1"
    print m.groups()

m = re.match(re2, serial)
if m:
    print "found for re2"
    print m.groups()
```

Gives output

```
found for re1
()
```

Which is what I expected. Using this code in C++ however:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(){
    std::string serial = "1600442";
    std::tr1::regex re1("1600442|7654321");
    std::tr1::regex re2("7895432");

    std::tr1::smatch match;

    std::cout << "re1:" << std::endl;
    std::tr1::regex_search(serial, match, re1);
    for (auto i = 0;i <match.length(); ++i)
            std::cout << match[i].str().c_str() << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl << "re2:" << std::endl;
    std::tr1::regex_search(serial, match, re2);
    for (auto i = 0;i <match.length(); ++i)
            std::cout << match[i].str().c_str() << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::string s;
    std::getline (std::cin,s);
}
```

gives me:

```
re1:
1600442
re2:
1600442
```

which is not what I expected. Why do I get match here?

Comment: Try wrap it between `(?:...)`

Comment: It seems the `smatch` variable does not get overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `smatch` does not get overwritten by the second call to `regex_search` thus, it is left intact and contains the first results.

You can move the regex searching code to a separate method:

```
void FindMeText(std::regex re, std::string serial) 
{
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex_search(serial, match, re);
    for (auto i = 0;i <match.length(); ++i)
            std::cout << match[i].str().c_str() << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::string serial = "1600442";
    std::regex re1("^(?:1600442|7654321)");
    std::regex re2("^7895432");
    std::cout << "re1:" << std::endl;
    FindMeText(re1, serial);
    std::cout << "re2:" << std::endl;
    FindMeText(re2, serial);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::string s;
    std::getline (std::cin,s);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that Python `re.match` searches for the pattern match at the start of string only, thus I suggest using `^` (start of string) at the beginning of each pattern.